# rails active record: limit how much is printed from text columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a text column in my Users table that contains a large serialized array. Whenever I print a user object in the rails console, I can't see any of the other fields because the text column prints so much. Is there any way to limit how much of the text column is printed? The database is postgres.

```
> puts User.first
> #<User id: 1, uid: "323", name: "overlord", big_serialized_array: ["dafsdfa", "dafsdf" #and it goes on for over 1000 lines ...
```

Comment: Are you printing the object in the rails console? If so, it is supposed print up-to 50 char.

Comment: Yes I do something like "puts User.first" and it spews out way over 50 characters. My terminal shows the last 1000 lines and it's exceeding that. The text field stores a serialized array if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to your class:

```
def attribute_for_inspect(attr_name)
  value = read_attribute(attr_name)
  return super unless value.is_a?(Hash)
  value = value.inspect
  return value if value.length <= 50
  "#{value.inspect[0..50]}..."
end
```

Comment: In my case it was "return super unless value.is_a?(Array)" but this worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the number of characters to print : eg: `text[0..15]`